# Invoke-RestMethod as Service Account using PowerShell - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

PowerShell Version is `5.1.18362.1714`

I have access to a web service via a Service Account and I'm developing a script to get some data from said service.

The script first asks for credentials using `$credential = Get-Credential`.  I pass the script the credentials for the Service Account which has privilege to make the call to the service.

It then makes the call to the data service using:

```
try {
    $id = 1234
    $email = [String](Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://xyzdataservice.com:1000/XYZDataService.aspx?op=EMAIL_ADDRESS&FMT=XML&SCHEMA=IGNORE&ID=$id" -Credential $credential).DocumentElement.EMAIL_ADDRESS.Email_Address
    write-host $email
} catch [System.Net.WebException] {
    Write-Host $_.Exception
}
```

This catches the exception:

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

Now I'm pretty sure this account is authorized but is there a way to test this using some other mechanism?

The Data Service specifies that it uses `Basic Authentication` so passing the `PSCredential` object using the `-Credential` switch should be sufficient.

I also have access to a Test Data Service, however that uses my actual user account which connects and retrieves data fine using the `UseDefaultCredentials` switch.

Any advice on the best ways to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: Try converting your credentials to base64 and adding them to a header. `$Auth = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($credential.UserName + ":" + $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password)); $Headers = @{}; $Headers.Add("Authorization","Basic $Auth"); Invoke-RestMethod -Url "yoururl" -Headers $Headers`

Comment: Thanks for that I tried that with the same result unfortunately.  I think I need to go back to IT and double check this service account